# How to use create and use a function within d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to use a function within d3.js to avoid code repetition, but I am having trouble doing so.

For example, I have this line:

```
attr('transform', bi.translate(axisMargin.left + settings.category_padding, 0));
```

Now, `axisMargin.left` uses a function itself to get it's value, it does that like this:

```
leftMargin = d3.max(chart_data.Data, function(data) {
  return (data.Category.Name.length + (data.Group === null ? 0 : data.Group.Name.length)) * settings.text_letter_width + settings.text_min_width;
});
axisMargin = {
  left: leftMargin,
  bottom: 50,
  group: 5
};
```

However, I don't need to use anything like `d3.max` or need any other data, so I was wanting to do something like this:

```
category_padder = function() {
  return (parentRect.width < 940) ? 50 : 125;
};

settings = {
  category_padding: category_padder,
};
```

However it is not working, I get the error:

> Error:  attribute transform: Expected ')', "translate(358function ()

**Structure:**

```
bi.models.barchart = function(chart_data) {

    var settings, axisMargin, leftMargin, category_padder;

    // Settings and functions reside here

    // Calls to functions may be called here

    chart = function() {

        // Calls to functions may be called here too

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the returned value of `bi.translate`?

Comment: Don't you have call the fun. Like, `settings.category_padding=category_padder()` instead of `settings.category_padding=category_padder`?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Hmmm..... the returned value is this: `translate(358function () {
    return (parentRect.width < 940) ? 50 : 125;
  }, 0)` - the `358` would be the value of `axisMargin.left`.

Comment: As you can see, that's completely wrong. It should be just `attr("transform", "translate(" + (axisMargin.left + settings.category_padding) + ", 0)");`

Comment: @Sidtharthan I don't think it matters?

Comment: @Sidtharthan Actually, my bad, just tried it and it worked! Feel free to post as an answer.

Comment: Also, regarding what @Sidtharthan said, you have a function expression instead a function declaration... yet, you have to call it. It does matter.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Good point - noted.

Answer (score 0):

Start with something very basic that works, then add / change one element at a time, making sure it still works. For example, the second argument in `.attr('transform', _second_arg_)` needs to be either a direct *value* to which you set the `transform` attribute:

`.attr('transform', 'translate(100 100)')`

or a *function*, which, if you want, can access various bits of the bound data, most often the data point itself, as in

`.attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(100 ' + 16 * d.rowNum + ')';})`

The only reason for using a function as the second argument is when your attribute or style values depend on the *bound data*. Of course you can still do

`.attr('transform', myFunction(config))`

but it's no different to the invocation by value, as it breaks down to

`var transformValue = myFunction(config);
...
.attr('transform', transformValue)`

Again, start with the simplest thing, change one small thing at a time, check if it works, and repeat - it avoids getting stuck in a situation like this.